# How do I use @IdClass with JPA Repository?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I've been using a Spring JPA Repository interface to persist objects, and it works great!  But how do I use it when the `@Entity` defines an `@IdClass`?  The class is not embedded, but the fields are part of the object.  Is it expected I should create `findBy` methods that name all the composite fields?  Or is there a way to create a `findById` and pass the PK class?

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind - I found what I was missing.  I was extending `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` when what I really wanted was `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`.  It has a builtin method for `findOne` which accepts the PK class.